# how to read or display the txt file from the bottom in php

Tags: php

I want to simply display the txt file contents from the bottom to display the oldest posts.

```
     $file = file("./Files/data.txt");
        for($i =0;$i<count($file);$i++){
           print nl2br($file[$i]);
        }
```

This is the simple code to display text contents from top to bottom,but
I want the contents to be displayed from bottom to top. I would be glad if you 
can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
$file = file("./Files/data.txt");
```

to

```
$file = array_reverse(file("./Files/data.txt")); //<----- Reverse the array using array_reverse
```

No need to do any modifications on the loop , if you do the above change.

[`Source`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the file array order before passing it to the loop.

```
$file = file("./Files/data.txt");
$file = array_reverse($file);
for($i =0;$i<count($file);$i++){
   print nl2br($file[$i]);
}
```